# spring context:component-scan not working

Tags: spring

I have two packages holding spring controllers,I am not able to give actual names and packages.

```
com.test.controller------ABCController
com.test.xyz.controller------xyzController
```

I defined `<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>` in spring xml file,Spring able to find out controllers from `com.test.controller,XYZController` never called from spring container.it is saying no handler found.If i move `xyzcontroller` under package `com.test.controller`,then it's start working.

Please give any hints,why `XYZController` not working.

Thanks,

Raj

Answer (score 2):

Use `<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.**"/>` in your spring config, so it will scan for every annotated class in all subpackages of `com.test`.

Comment: It is saying /test.html handler not found.If i place same class under com.test.controller,It is working fine.